# got syntax error, unexpected end of file on my blade.php

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

got this error after inserting a @if inside a forelse and got a syntax error.

my home.blade.php:

```
@extends('master')

@section('header-intro')
  
@endsection

@section('main')
    <div class="container">
        <!--Section: Content-->
        <section class="text-center">

            <div class="posts">
                @forelse ($posts as $post)
                    @if (auth()->user()->id === $post->user->id)
                        <div class="post">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="bg-image hover-overlay ripple" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('storage/') . '/' . $post->thumb }}" class="img-post" />

                                    <a href="#!">
                                        <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.15);"></div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ $post->title }}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">
                                        {{ Str::limit($post->body, 58, '...') }}
                                    </p>
                                    <p>Autor: {{ $post->user->name }} - has {{ $post->comments->count() }} comments</p>
                                    <a href="{{ route('post', $post->slug) }}" class="btn btn-primary">read more</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @else
                        <h4>no posts for you</h4>
                        
                    @endforelse
            </div>

            @if (request()->input('search'))
                {{ $posts->appends(['search' => request()->input('search')])->links() }}
            @endif

        </section>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Forelse is to show the posts, and I need the if to show the post only to the "owners" inside this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to end your if statement, and then end your forelse. When there are no elements in the `$posts` array you call `@empty`

```php
  @endif
@empty
    <h4>no posts for you</h4>
@endforelse
```

It's confusing because you are using an if statement inside a forelse statement.

Your else is for when there are no elements to iterate. But you aren't ending the if statement.

Technically, for completeness here I would recommend repeating your @else inside the loop too as you have a scenario where you might have elements in the `$posts` array, but aren't for this auth'd user.

Perhaps something like:

```php
@forelse ($posts as $post)
  @if (auth()->user()->id === $post->user->id)
    ... your existing elements ...
  @else
    <h4>no posts for you</h4>
  @endif
@empty
  <h4>no posts</h4>
@endforelse
```

Comment: It worked for me, thanks!